# Deployment is getting failed if Consumer Group Id is provided to EventSourceMapping

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

On specifying the consumer_group_id to ManagedEventSourceMapping the deployment is getting failed with an error stating “Event source mapping already exists” but i am building unique consumer group id with uuid to ensure uniqueness on deployment. I don’t why i am facing this error.
We are using aws cdk in pyhton.

Tried deleting the trigger manually and then tried deploying it, then it is getting deployed. But I don’t want to do delete the event source mapping manually.

Comment: Please add some minimal code.

Comment: What is `ManagedEventSourceMapping`? If you're talking about `EventSourceMapping`, and if by `consumer_group_id` you mean `kafka_consumer_group_id`, then that value cannot be updated after deployment, as per the docs.